# Lazy Load On Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

I'm trying to implement lazy loading on a blogger blog, but I'm running into some issues.  The lazy load plugin in question is this one: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

So in the documentation, it says the images to be lazy-loaded should the the following html code format:

```
<img class="lazy" src="img/grey.gif" data-original="img/example.jpg"  width="640" heigh="480">
```

As it is the case with blogger posts, the blogger engine outputs the images in the following format:

```
<img class="lazy" src="img/myimage.png" width="640" heigh="480">
```

My question is, is it possible to make blogger output the image html with the first format, with the "grey.gif" spaceholder as default image src for all images, and the "data-original" attribute having the proper image URL so that the lazyloader actually works?

thanks in advance for any help :-)

Comment: Don't use some `class="lazy"` or javascript plugin for this use [loading="lazy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-loading) instead... no javascript needed... better SEO. Will make me happy that have JS disabled in mobile brave browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch to HTML view, then modify each img tag according to requirement of lazy load script.

Comment: that would be a little impractical for 2000+ images, wouldn't it?  I'm looking for some scripted solution to this problem.  Thanks for the suggestion anyway :-)

Comment: ya, you're right. . But as the HTML content generator is blogger, it's not possible to intercept it.
I needed same feature in wordpress. So, in wordpress, i created a shortcode for such images.
Anyways, for blogger, you can use search & replace to replace.
If it generates <img class="lazy" src="image.jpg" . . . . /> , you can search for [<img class="lazy" src] and replace by [<img class="lazy" src="noimage.jpg" data-original] . . It can take just 30 seconds :-)

Comment: @Hirvesh Don't you think it would be worth mentioning in the question that you're talking 2000+ images here? (Also: DON'T display 2000+ images on a page, lazy or not; THERE's your problem).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `loading='lazy'` in js function.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to do all this you can use the below lazy load script created specially for blogger blogs

`<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
(function(a){a.fn.lazyload=function(b){var c={threshold:0,failurelimit:0,event:"scroll",effect:"show",container:window};if(b){a.extend(c,b)}var d=this;if("scroll"==c.event){a(c.container).bind("scroll",function(b){var e=0;d.each(function(){if(a.abovethetop(this,c)||a.leftofbegin(this,c)){}else if(!a.belowthefold(this,c)&&!a.rightoffold(this,c)){a(this).trigger("appear")}else{if(e++>c.failurelimit){return false}}});var f=a.grep(d,function(a){return!a.loaded});d=a(f)})}this.each(function(){var b=this;if(undefined==a(b).attr("original")){a(b).attr("original",a(b).attr("src"))}if("scroll"!=c.event||undefined==a(b).attr("src")||c.placeholder==a(b).attr("src")||a.abovethetop(b,c)||a.leftofbegin(b,c)||a.belowthefold(b,c)||a.rightoffold(b,c)){if(c.placeholder){a(b).attr("src",c.placeholder)}else{a(b).removeAttr("src")}b.loaded=false}else{b.loaded=true}a(b).one("appear",function(){if(!this.loaded){a("<img />").bind("load",function(){a(b).hide().attr("src",a(b).attr("original"))[c.effect](c.effectspeed);b.loaded=true}).attr("src",a(b).attr("original"))}});if("scroll"!=c.event){a(b).bind(c.event,function(c){if(!b.loaded){a(b).trigger("appear")}})}});a(c.container).trigger(c.event);return this};a.belowthefold=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).height()+a(window).scrollTop()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().top+a(c.container).height()}return d<=a(b).offset().top-c.threshold};a.rightoffold=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).width()+a(window).scrollLeft()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().left+a(c.container).width()}return d<=a(b).offset().left-c.threshold};a.abovethetop=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).scrollTop()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().top}return d>=a(b).offset().top+c.threshold+a(b).height()};a.leftofbegin=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).scrollLeft()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().left}return d>=a(b).offset().left+c.threshold+a(b).width()};a.extend(a.expr[":"],{"below-the-fold":"$.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})","above-the-fold":"!$.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})","right-of-fold":"$.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})","left-of-fold":"!$.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})"})})(jQuery);$(function(){$("img").lazyload({placeholder:"http://i22.servimg.com/u/f22/15/42/72/40/grey10.gif",effect:"fadeIn",threshold:"-50"})})//]]></script>`

You can replace http://i22.servimg.com/u/f22/15/42/72/40/grey10.gif with other image link as a placeholder.

**Source link:** http://101helper.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-speed-up-your-blogger-blog.html